# How can one use one's own SVG in Font Awesome?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I have a custom made .svg file called "carport.svg". I would like to use it as if it was already included in FontAwesome and therefore use the FontAwesome infrastructure. I have placed my file in the \svgs\solid folder.

What more do I need to do to import it fully? I would like to then write in my HTML:

```
<i class="fas fa-carport"></i>
```

Comment: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Customize-Font-Awesome#svg-framework

Comment: added a detailed answer since a link only isn't accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

To use the Font Awesome icons, add the following line inside the  section of your HTML page:

```
<link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Refer to https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use

Answer (score 0):

You can find the steps in the following [link](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Customize-Font-Awesome#svg-framework). You will need to have you SVG path define as only one `path` element and nothing more (like any SVG icon) then you simply add the following code:

```
var CustomIcon = {
  prefix: 'fac', /* your own prefix OR use any of the exiting ones (fab, far, fas)*/
  iconName: 'custom-icon', /* The name of your icon*/
  icon: [150, 150, [], 'e105', 'M ...'] /* The viewbox, the unicode, the path*/
}

FontAwesome.library.add(
  CustomIcon
)
```

Simple example of adding a triangle icon:

```js
var faTriangle = {
  prefix: 'fas',
  iconName: 'tri',
  icon: [64, 64, [], 'e521', 'M8 48 L56 48 L32 12 Z']
}

FontAwesome.library.add(
  faTriangle
)
```

```css
i,svg {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/js/all.js"></script>

<i class="fas fa-tri fa-5x"></i>
<i class="fas fa-tri fa-8x"></i>
<i class="fas fa-tri fa-10x"></i>
```